# How to loop list and sum particular items in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to ask for advice from more advanced programmers in python. I have a list with information

```py
stream = [
    '2018-01-01,user1,3',
    '2018-01-07,user1,4',
    '2018-03-29,user1,1',
    '2018-04-04,user1,13',
    '2018-01-05,user2,7',
    '2018-06-14,user3,4',
    '2018-07-02,user3,10',
    '2018-03-21,user4,19',
    '2018-03-22,user4,4',
    '2018-04-22,user4,8',
    '2018-05-03,user4,9',
    '2018-05-11,user4,11',
]
```

I need to get result like this

```py
total_logs_by_user = user1 : 21
                     user2 : 7
                     user3 : 14
                     user4 : 51
```

What I already did so far, is like this:

```py
datas = []
for data in stream:
    print(data[:11])
    datas.append(data[11:])

print(datas)
```

```
    ['user1,3',
     'user1,4',
     'user1,1',
     'user1,13',
     'user2,7',
     'user3,4',
     'user3,10',
     'user4,19',
     'user4,4',
     'user4,8',
     'user4,9',
     'user4,11']
```

Then I separate **users** and **logs** amount:

```py
users = []
logs = []
for a in datas:
    #print(a[:5])
    users.append(a[:5])
    logs.append(a[6:])
```

And now, when I am trying to `zip(users, logs)` I am not getting the proper results. Anyways, my goal here is ***to sum logs per user***. Appreciate all possible solutions.

Comment: What improper results are you getting? How are you zipping? You gave a bunch of background but left out the actually relevant stuff.

Comment: Did the `streams` object come from a `.csv` file by chance? It's the same format, and if so, there are better ways to go about doing what you want to do if it was/is.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful in the way you handle your input data. If the usernames change (in terms of their length), using fixed offsets is going to break. However, as they appear to be comma delimited, you could do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

stream = [
    '2018-01-01,user1,3',
    '2018-01-07,user1,4',
    '2018-03-29,user1,1',
    '2018-04-04,user1,13',
    '2018-01-05,user2,7',
    '2018-06-14,user3,4',
    '2018-07-02,user3,10',
    '2018-03-21,user4,19',
    '2018-03-22,user4,4',
    '2018-04-22,user4,8',
    '2018-05-03,user4,9',
    '2018-05-11,user4,11',
]

D = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for e in stream:
    t = e.split(',')
    D[t[1]] += int(t[2])

for k, v in D.items():
    print(f'{k} : {v}')
```

**Output:**

```
user1 : 21
user2 : 7
user3 : 14
user4 : 51
```

Comment: yes, this solution works just exactly how I have expected

Comment: Can this line be changed to - `D = defaultdict(int)` instead?

Comment: No - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict